# How to plot trading signals on graph with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, trading

Can anyone help me please with the following? I am struggling with plotting 'buy' and 'sell' signals on my plot. The logic is following:

I am buying if `w` is less than `1.804482 - std_err` and selling at `1.804482` or if `w` is less than `1.804482 - std_err*1.5` (stop loss).

I am selling if `w` is greater than `1.804482 + std_err` and buying at `1.804482` or if `w` is greater than `1.804482 - std_err*1.5` (stop loss).

If anyone also would hint with the way of calculating profits that will be terrific.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4),dpi=100)

plt.plot(w,color='black')

plt.axhline(1.804482,c='green',lw=1,ls='--')
plt.axhline(1.804482 + std_err,color='blue',ls='--',lw=0.75)
plt.axhline(1.804482 - std_err,color='blue',ls='--',lw=0.75)

plt.axhline(1.804482 + std_err*1.5,color='red',ls='--',lw=0.75)
plt.axhline(1.804482 - std_err*1.5,color='red',ls='--',lw=0.75)

buy = w[w < 1.804482 - std_err]
sell = w[w > 1.804482 + std_err]  


plt.plot(buy,color='g',linestyle='None',marker='*')
plt.plot(sell,color='r',linestyle='None',marker='*')


ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%b-%-y'))
fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.xticks(rotation=45,fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12)

plt.grid(b=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for editing my question, now I hope someone will help to solve it.